# How to manage creating a UITableViewCells?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Would you guyz be so kind to help me with such question:
I have to fill the tableView with cells and I also have an array with objects to fill cells with.
The question is - how to skip creating a cell if the object doesn't meet some conditions? I mean how to write something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if(objectIsOk) {
    //create cell
} 
else {
    //do nothing
}
return cell;
```

NOTE: I don't have an access to that array of objects it gives me an object per indexPath.row dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure as to what you mean by "skip creating a cell". Your table view data source is *required* to return a cell for each `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` call, which will get called for each row in each section that you have said the table will contain.

If you want to return a blank cell then why not just do something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    if (objectIsOk) {
        // Create normal cell
    } else {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"BlankCell"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

You could also return height of zero in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method to make it appear that it's not there, like so:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (objectIsOk) {
        return 44.0f;
    } else {
        return 0.0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that I must return cell but I need that this blank cell won't be visible at all :(

Comment: Then what's wrong with my answer? What do you mean by "won't be visible at all"? It needs to be there... You could also return height of zero in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method to make it appear that it's not there.

Comment: >You could also return height of zero in the heightForRowAtIndexPath: delegate method to make it appear that it's not there.

This is what works for me thanks!Could you form this answer as Answer so that I can accept it?